# What is the SQL query to filter og Admin Accounts?

Tags: views, organic-groups, database

I currently have the following SQL statement that gives me a list of all of my og nodes and their associated owner. I am having trouble nesting my JOIN statements to add the name of the owner from the users table. Any hints? Thanks

```
SELECT 
    label AS `Group Name`,
    gid AS `Group ID`,
    etid AS `Node ID`,
    type AS `Type`,
    b.nid AS `Owner ID`
    FROM `prefix_og` a
        LEFT JOIN `prefix_node` b
            ON a.etid=b.nid
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked nicely... how can I make this available in a view?:

```
SELECT 
a.label AS `Group Name`, 
a.gid AS `Group ID`, 
a.etid AS `Node ID`, 
b.type AS `Type`, 
b.uid AS `Owner ID`,
c.name AS `Owner Username`,
d.realname AS `Owner Realname`,
e.rid AS `OG Role ID`
FROM `prefix_og` a 
LEFT JOIN `prefix_node` b 
ON a.etid=b.nid 
LEFT JOIN `prefix_users` c 
ON b.uid=c.uid 
LEFT JOIN `prefix_realname` d 
ON b.uid=d.uid 
LEFT JOIN `prefix_og_users_roles` e 
ON b.uid=e.uid
```